# Accidental in app purchase by minor

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

My 3 year-old son made an accidental in app purchase of around 270 pounds. I tried refund my money to my account but couldn't do it. Please help me refund my money because I can't afford to lose money that way.

Answer (score 5):

You can request refund on the website [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.do?caller=itsiapm&PGF=PGF51002&category_id=SC0060&symptom_id=20515&locale=en_US), selecting "iTunes Store" product and "Unintentional/unauthorized In-App Purchase by a minor" topic.

Here is a good article for this case: http://www.macworld.com/article/2140066/how-to-get-an-app-store-refund-for-kids-accidental-in-app-purchases.html